# Should I take 9 year old Tylenol with codeine?

Tags: medications, expiration-dates

Recently I strained a muscle in my shoulder; the throbbing pain got so bad that I, uncharacteristically, took pills for the pain; namely some old Robaxal that I had sitting around from 6 or 7 years ago.

That stopped the throbbing temporary, but now 24 hours later the unbearable pain is returning. I have some Tylenol with codeine that a dentist prescribed after a double root canal, but I didn't finish the prescription.

Is it safe to take it now?

Comment: I don't know where in the world you are, but here in the UK, medications usually have a use by date on the package.  If they have passed that date you don't know what effect it would have.  Would it make you more ill?

Comment: It doesn't have a use by date, only the date it was prescribed.

Comment: I'd **strongly recommend** talking to a doctor and not taking old medication. The risks if it was not safe are just too high.

Comment: Furthermore, any pain that prevents you from functioning normally, deserves a visit to the doctor's. We can't provide personal medical advice over the internet, because we simply can't have proper insight into the situation without seeing (and examining) you in person. Your doctor can do that.